# Как создать объект типа класса Class для параметризованного листа?

Tags: java, классы

Есть параметризованный лист:

```
List<Zuzu> list;
```

Как создать объект типа класса Class для этого параметризованного листа?

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @LEQADA Я хочу создать объект типа класса Class. К примеру для ZuZu это будет так, Class zuzu = Zuzu.class; А как я могу это сделать для параметризованного листа?

Comment: List - интерфейс. А Zuzu - класс. Зачем вы хотите из интерфейса получить класс? Какова причина?

Comment: @LEQADA Хорошо, а как это можно тогда сделать для ArrayList? Для тестирования. В метод будет передаваться любая  реализации List, которая параметризована по Zuzu. Там  у меня мок объекты.

Comment: Для тестирования чего?

Comment: @minotna вы хотите во время выполнения понять, какой класс указан как generic у List?

Comment: @LEQADA Короче говоря, я хочу протестировать один метод моего приложения сервисного слоя, который дергает методы дао слоя. Дао слой я замокировал. В сам метод передается List<Zuzu>.

Comment: @LEQADA Вы думаете что нельзя создать объект типа класса Class для интерфейса? Мне кажется можно.У этого самого класса Class есть метод даже такой cast(Casts an object to the class or interface represented by this Class object). Да и ведь у нас для каждого интерфейса тоже создается файл с расширением .class, так почему же мы тогда не можем создать объект типа класса Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плохая практика, но можно вот как-то так

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Integer objectOfList = new A().getObjectOfList();
    }

}

class A extends Parent<Integer> {

}

class Parent<T> {

    private Class<T> typeClass;
    private List<T> mylist;

    public T getObjectOfList() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (null == mylist) {
            return null;
        }
        return typeClass.newInstance();
    }
}
```